# Chrome extension not running in the background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So basicly this is my first time creating a chrome extension and I managed to implement the feature that I want and it is working ONLY when the tab is opened and visible on the screen. When I switch tabs to do some other stuff, extension doesn't clicking the button on the webpage.(When the tab is active on my screen it is clicking, when I switch to any other tab, it is stopping to click. Or when I watch netflix/youtube fullscreen, it is also stopping to press the button) And what my extension does is, it is clicking a button on the webpage in random duration based on the user input. So, after doing some research I found out that I am applying all the things in content.js and not using background.js. At this point I am so confused how to apply the architecture corrreclty and how to move the codes. Or if this is the solution for my problem or not? I need my seniors advices and possible solution ideas.

manifest.json

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AutoClicker UI",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["content.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.travian.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
let clickingInterval;
let clickDuration = 5; // Default duration in minutes

console.log('Extension loaded.');

function clickTargetButton() {

  const button = document.querySelector('#stickyWrapper > button.textButtonV2.buttonFramed.startAllFarmLists.rectangle.withText.green');


  if (button) {
    button.click();
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  } else {
    console.log('Button not found or XPath incorrect.');
  }
}

let clickCount = 0;


function startClicking(duration) {
  const userDuration = duration || 5; // Default user input is 5 if no duration is provided

  const lowerBoundary = Math.max(1, userDuration - 1); // Ensure lower boundary minimum is 1
  const upperBoundary = userDuration + 1; // Upper boundary (6)

  function clickWithRandomDuration() {
    const randomizedMinutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperBoundary - lowerBoundary)) + lowerBoundary;
    const randomizedSeconds = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
    const randomizedDuration = randomizedMinutes * 60 * 1000 + randomizedSeconds * 1000;

    clickTargetButton(); // Click the button after the randomized duration
    console.log(`Next click in: ${randomizedMinutes} minutes ${randomizedSeconds} seconds`);

    setTimeout(clickWithRandomDuration, randomizedDuration); // Use setTimeout instead of setInterval
  }
  clickTargetButton(); // Click the button immediately
  setTimeout(clickWithRandomDuration, userDuration * 60 * 1000); // Initial delay for the first random click
}
  
  
function stopClicking() {
    clearInterval(clickingInterval);
  }

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === 'startClicking') {
    const duration = parseInt(message.duration);
    if (!isNaN(duration)) {
      startClicking(duration);
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid duration provided.');
    }
  } else if (message.action === 'stopClicking') {
    stopClicking();
  }
});
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const duration = document.getElementById('interval').value;
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'startClicking', duration: duration });
  });
});

document.getElementById('stopButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'stopClicking' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Web sites often stop processing events when the tab is not active. You can drag the tab out of the window, which creates a new window for this tab, then you can switch to your main window.

Comment: @wOxxOm this helps, I appreciate your answer! But are there any other ways to solve it or this is the only solution? For the background.js, should I split some of my codes to there? Or is it okay right now?

Comment: There's no need for `background` section here, you can remove it. As for other solutions, it depends on the site, and you'll have to override the way it detects inactive tabs e.g. addEventListener for `visibilitychange` or `blur` events in [the MAIN world](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm okay thank you. Then im gonna leave it like this and work for the UI. You always answer my questions so thanks a lot sir!